# Windows form Create 10 textBox dynamic this text value how to access?

Tags: c#, winforms

Dynamic 10 textbox create all text value how to access in button click event in windows form application

Comment: Do you assign names to the individual textboxes?

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way to do this is create a list to keep textbox's references.

```
List<TextBox> textBoxList = new List<TextBox>();

for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox();
    textBoxList.Add(textBox);

    // do the rest of work.
}
```

You can get its reference inside click event handler like below.

```
// inside button's click event.
foreach (var textBox in textBoxList)
{
    // get text and do the work.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.Text = "ABC";
this.Controls.Add(txt);

private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)           
 {                              
  if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))                               
    MessageBox.Show(ctl.Text);               
 }

}
```

Comment: Its WinForm, not a Web application

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way assign something to the tag property that help you to identify the textbox. For example a number or an enum value.

Then casting the click event sender to a text box and look in the tag which one is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of 10 text boxes dynamically place all the text boxes
You can access the text value based on the array values (0-9) of it